# Which facebook account to use for facebook app review?

Tags: facebook, facebook-android-sdk

If a company wants to submit an Android app for facebook app review then which facebook account should be used? Should an owner's fb account be used to submit App for review? Because facebook doesn't have any such feature of creating account for a company.

What is the proper way?

Answer (score 0):

**The account of any user who is able/allowed to submit the App for review.** Of course there are no company profiles, it has to be a real user - fake accounts are not allowed.

Comment: You mean from an owner's personal account a company has to register, right?

Comment: not sure how else to explain, just use one of the admins of the app. read the bold text.